# SQLITE using a python variables with a select statement

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I'm finding this issue difficult to solve: I'm trying to use a SQL SELECT statement near a PYTHON VARIABLE , which results in a syntax error. HERE IS MY CODE

```
item_sql = """
        INSERT or REPLACE INTO item(i_name, i_qty)
        VALUES
        ((?), SELECT s_qty + (?) from item)
        """
self.cur.execute(item_sql, (s_item, s_qty))
self.con.commit()
```

What I am trying to achieve is; after inserting the `i_name` and `i_qty`; then in the next insertion, to sum the previous `i_qty` to the last inserted `i qty` values.

Is there a way to resolve this conflict of using a SQL SELECT statement near a PYTHON VAR or another way to achieve my desired result.

thanks.

Comment: why exactly do you want to use sql here?

Comment: HI, because i'm inserting in to a sqlite database, in which i'm storing the items and their quantity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want to insert a new row to the table but if the `i_name` already exists then you just want to update `i_qty` by adding the quantity parameter to the existing quantity.
If this is the case and there is already set a unique constraint or index for the column `i_name`, then you can do it with [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html):

```
item_sql = """
        INSERT INTO item(i_name, i_qty) VALUES (?, ?)
        ON CONFLICT(i_name) DO UPDATE SET
        i_qty = i_qty + EXCLUDED.i_qty
        """
```

With `UPSERT` you can insert a new row to the table, with the statement `INSERT INTO ....`, but if a unique constraint violation occurs, then the statement after `ON CONFLICT(...) DO` will be executed.

If you version of SQLite does not support `UPSERT`, you can execute 2 separate statements:

```
UPDATE item SET i_qty = i_qty + ? WHERE i_name = ?
```

If the value of `i_name` does not exist in the table then nothing will happen, but if it exists then the row will be updated.
And then:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO item (i_name, i_qty) VALUES (?, ?)
```

If the value of `i_name` does not exist in the table then it will be inserted, but if it exists then nothing will happen because of `IGNORE`.

Comment: Hi, tried the code however there seems to be an syntax error, near ON,

Comment: it seems my python's sqlite version is 3.14.2, if such these new command will not work right?, btw thanks for the answer :)

Comment: You need version 3.24.0

Comment: @Mattey check my edited answer for an alternative.

Comment: i'v just update my python's sql, and the solution you gave worked, thanks for the help